# NG Bootstrap Popover is not shown properly on tables

Tags: html, css, popover, ng-bootstrap

I am using popover of ngbootstrap on tables items click.

tables css:

```css
{
    position: relative;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

because I need to scroll on Y axis.

but the popover is not showed all ( I tried to put it on top also but same )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to override bootstrap CSS? If yes, try `overflow: scroll !important;` to see if it does take change. It is not the most recommended way but you can have a workaround.